# Unable to run the test for the webapps running in cloud/remote server ( application is accessible via browser only through VPN). Getting error

Tags: testrigor

Unable to run the test for the webapps running in cloud ( application is accessible via browser only through VPN). Getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You must first setup a tunnel from testRigor to your machine, then try accessing the page.

1. Read the tunnel documentation.
2. Set up a tunnel on your machine.
3. Request a port from testRigor support
4. Then run your test

Docs for setting up a tunnel:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MMQ9WBwRTSPUI589PKv5YxiyM7r5rE1K5iP_Dj5xl0Q/edit#